# Train-Test split for Time Series Data to be used for LSTM

Tags: python, keras, time-series, regression, lstm

```
values = df.values
train, test = train_test_split(values)

#Split into train and test
X_train, y_train = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
X_test, y_test = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
```

Executing the above code splits the time series dataset into training- 75% and testing 25%. I want to control the train-test split as 80-20 or 90-10. **Can someone please help me understand how to split the dataset into any ratio I want?**

The concept is borrowed from https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/.

Note : **I cannot split the dataset randomly for train and  test and the most recent values have to be for testing**. I have included a screenshot of my dataset.

[image]If anyone can interpret the code, please do help me understand the above. Thanks.

Comment: **def load_data(filename, seq_len, normalise_window)** from [here](https://www.jakob-aungiers.com/articles/a/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction) works fine... I would also add split for x_validate, y_validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should divide your data into train and test using slicing or sklearn's [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) (remember to use `shuffle=False` for time-series data).

```
#divide data into train and test
train_ind = int(len(df)*0.8)
train = df[:train_ind]
test = df[train_ind:]
```

Then, you want to use Keras' [TimeseriesGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/TimeseriesGenerator) to generate sequences for the LSTM to use as input. This [blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-the-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-forecasting-in-keras/) does a good job explaining it's usage.

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

n_input = 2 #length of output
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train, targets=train, length=n_input)
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I wasn't aware of the shuffle parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the documentation.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Basically, you'll want to do something like `train_test_split(values,test_size=.2,shuffle=False)`

`test_size=.2` tells the function to make the test size 20% of the input data (you can similarly specify trainset size with `train_size=n`, but in the absence of this specification the function will use `1-test_size`, i.e. the complement of the test set).

`shuffle=False` tells the function not to randomly shuffle the order.

Comment: Got it. I did not know about the shuffle value. Thank you.